# mongo MongoCursorNotFoundException in long-running query loop

Tags: mongodb, exception

I have a simple query loop that gets a MongoCursorNotFoundException after processing about 44,000 of 96,945 documents in around 93 minutes.

```
MongoIterable<MasterDocument> query = masterCollection.find().noCursorTimeout(true);
    for (MasterDocument masterDocument : query) { ... do some stuff ... }
```

The "do some stuff" part takes a while, which is why the entire loop takes so long.

My problem is that I get this exception after handling maybe half of the documents in the collection.

I am running both the client application and the mongod server locally on my Windows 10 laptop, accessing the server via localhost.

The server log shows lots of messages like this:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-04T20:21:35.510-08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"conn27","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"master_database.MasterCollection","command":{"find":"MasterCollection","filter":{"hashCode":1753339282},"$db":"master_database","lsid":{"id":{"$uuid":"6a252f51-2c6e-4c01-ae03-1a80aab109e0"}}},"planSummary":"COLLSCAN","keysExamined":0,"docsExamined":96944,"cursorExhausted":true,"numYields":96,"nreturned":0,"queryHash":"DBC59907","planCacheKey":"DBC59907","reslen":121,"locks":{"ReplicationStateTransition":{"acquireCount":{"w":97}},"Global":{"acquireCount":{"r":97}},"Database":{"acquireCount":{"r":97}},"Collection":{"acquireCount":{"r":97}},"Mutex":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}}},"storage":{},"protocol":"op_msg","durationMillis":147}}
```

The last of these messages is followed by:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-04T20:21:35.521-08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn27","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:58990","connectionId":27,"connectionCount":14}}
```

{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-04T20:21:35.522-08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn26","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:58989","connectionId":26,"connectionCount":13}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-04T20:21:35.922-08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20883,   "ctx":"conn25","msg":"Interrupted operation as its client disconnected","attr":{"opId":310196}}

I have tried:

- Using "noCursorTimeout(true)" on the query cursor (as shown above)
- Starting the server with "mongod --setParameter localLogicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=240". This last seems to have caused additional log messages that say "error":"Location13111: wrong type for field (expireAfterSeconds) long != int"

I am using mongod 4.4 and the latest mongo java api.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to increase the default cursor idle timeout to bigger value in all shards and mongos:

check the parameter(default is 10 min = 600000 ms ):

```
use admin
db.runCommand({getParameter:1, cursorTimeoutMillis: 1})
```

and update to bigger value:

```
use admin
db.runCommand({setParameter:1, cursorTimeoutMillis: 600000000 })
```

also the COLSCAN in your logs indicate that you dont use indexes in your query , maybe you need to create one on "hashCode" ...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the response.

It turned out that my application ran to completion once I started mongod with "--setParameter localLogicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=240, despite the error message that I saw in the console log.

You are absolutely right that I should have an index on "hashCode".  (I had one before but forgot to recreate it after recreating the collection.)